# Regex match pair ocurrences of a specific character

Tags: regex

I've been trying to make a regex that satisfies this conditions:

- The word consists of characters a,b
- The number of b characters must be pair (consecutive or not)

So for example:

- abb -> accepted
- abab -> accepted
- aaaa -> rejected
- baaab -> accepted

So far i got this: ([a]*)(((b){2}){1,})

As you can see i know very little about the matter, this checks for pairs but it does still accept words with odd number of b's.

Comment: I think by "pair", what you mean is "even" - that is, a multiple of two?

Comment: I think you are a better of writing a parser, i.e. count number of `b`s and return true if `!(count % 2) && count > 0`.  Couple of hints: you have to match the whole string ^(...)$ otherwise any [^ab] in beginning or end would not be rejected.  You didn't say what regex engine you use, but I would use a back-reference for the pairing.  I don't understand the requirement.  Why is abb accepted by aaaa is not?  count of 0 is even.

Comment: (and you of course need to ensure that the only non-`b` are `a`)

Comment: This is more easily solved with character arrays rather than regular expressions. Is there a reason you have to use regexps for this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate language so that non-regex solutions can also be offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex to check for some number of `a`s with an even number of `b`s:

```
^(?:a*ba*ba*)+$
```

This looks for 1 or more occurrences of 2 `b`s surrounded by some number (which may be 0) `a`s.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5Dt7mE/2)

Note this will match `bb` (or `bbbb`, `bbbbbb` etc.). If you don't want to do that, the easiest way is to add a positive lookahead for an `a`:

```
^(?=b*a)(?:a*ba*ba*)+$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/49XSkO/1)

Answer (score 0):

### Checking an Array of Characters Against Two Conditionals

While you *could* do this using [regular expressions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html), it would be simpler to solve it by applying some conditional checks against your two rules against an [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html) of characters created with [String#chars](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-chars). For example, using Ruby 3.1.2:

```rb
# Rule 1: string contains only the letters `a` and `b`
# Rule 2: the number of `b` characters in the word is even
#
# @return [Boolean] whether the word matches *both* rules
def word_matches_rules word
  char_array = word.chars
  char_array.uniq.sort == %w[a b] and char_array.count("b").even?
end

words = %w[abb abab aaaa baaab]
words.map { |word| [word, word_matches_rules(word)] }.to_h
#=> {"abb"=>true, "abab"=>true, "aaaa"=>false, "baaab"=>true}
```

Regular expressions are very useful, but string operations are generally faster and easier to conceptualize. This approach also allows you to add more rules or verify intermediate steps without adding a lot of complexity.

There are probably a number of ways this could be simplified further, such as using a [Set](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) or methods like [Array#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-26) or [Array#-](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-2D). However, my goal with this answer was to make the code (and the encoded rules you're trying to apply) easier to read, modify, and extend rather than to make the code as minimalist as possible.